# Mac - Svn Client

Tags: osx, subversion

I am new user on Mac and i would like recommendation for SVN Client such as 'Svn Tortoise" on Windows.

please share you comments

Answer (score 0):

Versions (https://versionsapp.com) is a SVN client. It was last updated however (as of March 2020) in March 2018.